# String interpolation not working in Sinatra redirect

Tags: ruby, sinatra

When I use this method:

```
patch '/posts/:id' do
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.update(name: params[:name], content: params[:content])
  redirect to '/posts/#{post.id}'
end
```

I get the error `ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:9393/posts/#{post.id}`

But when I either hardcode the id or concatenate the strings like this:
`redirect to '/posts/' + post.id.to_s`

it works fine.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby the string literals declared in single quotes *are not interpolated*, unlike double-quoted literals:

```
"#{42}"
#⇒ "42"
'#{42}'
#⇒ "\#{42}"
```

So, just change single quotes to double quotes in the argument to `redirect to`.